# Use match in replace of find and replace utility in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, regex, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, regex-group

In my jupyter notebook I want to replace the print functions
with a wrapper function.

I can match the print statement with a javascript regexp `print\\(.*\\)` but from there I am not sure how to use the match again in the replacement text field:

```
def verb_printer(msg, verb):
    if verb:
        print(msg)
```

I tried something like `verb_printer($1)` to access the match, but it didn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: will this work for you? `const result = str.replace(/\bprint(\s*\()([^)]+)\)/gm, 'verb_printer$1$2)');`

Comment: This doesn't help me. Probably I did not describe the problem well. I added an image to the initial post.

Comment: Could you please add en example with your given input and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original expression is just fine, we would be only adding a capturing group `()` so that when we would be replacing it with `verb_printer($1)`, our desired string has been already captured:

```
(print\(.*\))
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wxukYM/1)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(print\(.*\))/gm;
const str = `def verb_printer(msg, verb):
    if verb:
        print(msg)
`;
const subst = `verb_printer($1)`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```